# Shiro.ini file is missing in Zeppelin

Tags: shiro, apache-zeppelin

I am not able to find shiro.ini file inside conf folder, i  need to enable authentication but i am not able to find shiro.ini.

I tried adding shiro.ini file manually but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

there should be `shiro.ini.template` file under `conf/` folder. so you can just copy it into new file `shiro.ini`.

Update: shiro integration is available starting from version 0.6.0

Comment: Prior to Zeppelin branch 6.0 there is no shiro.ini.template and shiro.ini. I am using branch 5.6

Comment: actually multi-tenancy and shiro integration was introduced from branch 0.6, so it wouldn't be possible to enable shiro auth prior to version 0.6.0.

Comment: Thanks @Khalid Huseynov, i upgraded to latest version